# Вывести картинки в определенных альбомах

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть две таблицы images и albums. Пользователь например 2 альбома и загружает две разные картинки, но у меня выводит все картинки в любых альбомах помогите, пожалуйста. Вот скрипт вывода.

```
<?php
$album_id = $_GET['id'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images`  WHERE users_id='$myrow[id]' ");
while ($run = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $pic = $run['filename'];
    ?>

    <div class='img'>
<img src="img/<?php echo $pic ?>"/>
    </div>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: напишите организацию (колонки) таблиц.

Comment: @Fike
images.img_id,title,filename,description,when,comments_count,album_id,users_id,love. таблица albums.id, name,users_id

Comment: @Fike ставлю место юзера_ид,альбом_ид вовсе все фотографии пропадают.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
images
img_id,title,filename,description,when,comments_count,album_id,users_id,love

albums
id, name,users_id
```

Как я понял при добавлении нового альбома в таблице albums указывается id пользователя, также при добавлении изображения указывается в таблице images id альбома в который загружается фотография и дублируется id пользователя.
В такой ситуации можно поступить проще. В таблице images удалите поле users_id.
Тогда для выборки всех фотографий пользователя применяйте такой запрос:

```
select images.filename,albums.name from images inner join albums on (images.album_id = albums.id) where albums.users_id = '$userID'
```

Рекомендую почитать документацию по join'ам .

Comment: Удалить не вариант, так как у меня две вкладки.Есть все фотографии, а есть фотоальбомы.

Comment: @terantul
Теперь выводит, но не все фотографии, а фотографии которые загружены в разные альбомы, хотелось что бы именно фотографии, данного альбома.

Comment: Измените параметры выборки where albums.users_id = '$userID' and albums.id = '$albumID' . Почитайте документацию и уроки для начинающих. Ваша задача элементарна. Установите себе графический SQL редактор (тот же EMS SQL Manager), очень помогает в изучении тонкостей работы с БД.